# Вертикальное расположение элементов gallery

Tags: android, gallery

Как сделать так, чтобы элементы выводились не вертикально, а горизонтально?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Галерея(именно класс Gallery) и так выводит элементы горизонтально, GridView выводит элементы и горизонтально и вертикально(можно как угодно задать столбцы и строки, в теории как угодно). Для горизонтальной прокрутки элементов, я например, использую ViewPager из Android Support Library, который нынче заменяет глючную галерею(класс Gallery).

Comment: Я все напутал. Я хотел вертикальное расположение элементов, а не горизональное

Comment: @makavelka Я вам ответил и на то и на то) GridView с одним столбцом юзайте.